# Want to get volume using 3dprint addon but get Problem From blender Console

Tags: scripting, add-on

Problem in Console

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 51, in invoke   
  File "\Text", line 51, in <genexpr>
  File "\Text", line 43, in calc_volume
NameError: name 'mesh_helpers' is not defined
location: <unknown location>:-1
```

````
import bpy, os
from bpy.types import Panel
from bpy.utils import register_class, unregister_class

import math

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import (
    IntProperty,
    FloatProperty,
)
import bmesh

class View3DPrintPanel:
    bl_category = "3D-Print"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        return obj is not None and obj.type == 'MESH' and obj.mode in {'OBJECT', 'EDIT'}
class VIEW3D_PT_print3d_transform(View3DPrintPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Transform"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.label(text="Scale ")
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.operator("mesh.print3d_scale_to_volume", text="Volume") 

class MESH_OT_print3d_scale_to_volume(Operator):
    bl_idname = "mesh.print3d_scale_to_volume"
    bl_label = "Scale to Volume"
    bl_description = "Scale edit-mesh or selected-objects to a set volume"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    volume_init: FloatProperty(
        options={'HIDDEN'},
    )
    volume: FloatProperty(
        name="Volume",
        unit='VOLUME',
        min=0.0,
        max=100000.0,
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        scale = math.pow(self.volume, 1 / 3) / math.pow(self.volume_init, 1 / 3)
        scale_fmt = clean_float(f"{scale:.6f}")
        self.report({'INFO'}, f"Scaled by {scale_fmt}")
        _scale(scale, self.report)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event): 
        def calc_volume(obj):
            bm = mesh_helpers.bmesh_copy_from_object(obj, apply_modifiers=True)
            volume = bm.calc_volume(signed=True)
            bm.free()
            return volume

        if context.mode == 'EDIT_MESH':
            volume = calc_volume(context.edit_object)
        else:
            volume = sum(calc_volume(obj) for obj in context.selected_editable_objects if obj.type == 'MESH')

        if volume == 0.0:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Object has zero volume")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        self.volume_init = self.volume = abs(volume)

        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

 



 

def register():
     register_class(VIEW3D_PT_print3d_transform)
 
def unregister():
     unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_print3d_transform)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```
````

Comment: Tested it. No error. You should explain a bit more what you've done.

Answer (score 2):

**Python NameError**

The error occurs on this line.

```
bm = mesh_helpers.bmesh_copy_from_object(obj, apply_modifiers=True)
```

and is informing you that `mesh_helpers` is not defined.

Assume you are doing a bit of copy paste to and from the 3D print addon, where no doubt `mesh_helpers` is imported and available, whereas you missed it. It  can be imported from the 3D print toolbox

```
from object_print3d_utils import mesh_helpers
```

may find similar issues with `clean_float` and `_scale`.

Comment: ... that means I ve not this error because print3D is activated in my env? ... mmm should ask on the meta: "how to upvote directly, without scrolling and clicking when batFINGER answer a question"... should do but not sure the meta is about shortcut optimization...

Comment: TBH didn't test the code, simply couldn't see any ref in code to `mesh_helpers`  so ran with it.  Would need to press (invoke) the button to throw.

Comment: I'm sure you're honnest (100% sure!)... do you know what happens when such code is run and the original addon is already activated? Or should I ask a question about that?

Comment: Assume the issue is the operator in question is never registered and is using same id as original, whereas perhaps the OP did reg the new one, overriiding the original and throwing the error.